# etale vs zariski cohomology for coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme and $F$ a *coherent* sheaf on $X$. Does the etale cohomology of $F$ (i.e the cohomology of $F$ on the etale site of $X$) agree with the cohomology of $F$ on the Zariski site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They agree. In fact, you only need to assume quasicoherence; the key point is that the étale cohomology of a quasicoherent sheaf on an *affine* scheme vanishes in degrees $> 0$, just as for the Zariski topology.

For more details, see [tag `03DW`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03DW) in the Stacks project.